# When did sqlmag.com cease to exist, please?

Tags: sql-server

It obviously has been a while since I visited the sqlmag.com website.  I found it no longer exists but it appears that ITProToday owns it.  Can anyone tell me when this happened, please?

Answer (score 12):

[Penton Media filed for bankruptcy in 2010](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/sql-server-magazines-publisher-files-bankruptcy/), tried [reinventing themselves as SQL Server Pro in 2011](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/whats-in-a-name-sql-server-magazine-becomes-sql-server-pro), and then gradually phased out that SQL Server Pro brand into a general IT Pro Today site.